# During the Veeam backup of a Hyper-V virtual machine, a chain of the local backup SQL server breaks

Tags: hyper-v, veeam

Veeam makes a backup virtual machine on the Hyper-V server
On the Windows virtual machine there is a SQL server and conferences Local Backup using SQL to local drive
There is no access to the VM

During the backup of a virtual machine, a chain of the local backup SQL server breaks

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with a VM deployed on a datacenter, but Veeam team is not listening that they have an issue, the solution is to increase available RAM....